# Need Help on using map for functions in python

Tags: python, function

So I have written a function f(a, b). The structure is:

```
def f(a, b):
    global result

    def g(a, b):
        global result
        return result

    deg h(a):
        return a  # an updated a

    g(a, b)
    a = h(a)
    g(a, b)
    a = h(a)
    g(a, b)
    a = h(a)
    g(a, b)
    return result
```

- You can see that I have two sub-functions `g(a, b)` and `h(a)` in
  `f(a, b)`.
- I need to run `g(a, b)` to get the partial result
- Then I updated the `a`
- So that I can run `g(a, b)` again, to update the result.
- After 4 runs of `g(a, b)`, I got the full piece of result and return the value.

There must be a way to structure the process here that looks simpler and clearer.

I also tried:

```
g(a, b)
g(h(a), b)
g(h(h(a), b)
g(h(h(h(a), b)
```

And that looks hideous as well.

I need some suggestion to simply to structure here, maybe to use the map() or other high order functions? But I just couldn't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: `map` works on lists - it has nothing to do with high-order functions

Comment: What's the purpose of the `global result`? And why aren't you saving the value returned by the `g` function? And why doesn't `g` do anything with the arguments you pass it?

Comment: Have you considered using function returns instead of a global variable? Then a simple for loop would let you do it 4 times.

Comment: @PM2Ring I guess I was not giving enough details. The reason to do global result is because the g(a, b) only returns part of the result. So i need to update the a, and run g() again, the another part of the result. I have to run g() 4 times to get the full result. But again, I am a beginner here, if you can show me how to structure it without using global I will appreciate it. I understand that the use of global is often avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is something like that:

```
g(a, b)
a = h(a)
g(a, b)
a = h(a)
g(a, b)
a = h(a)
g(a, b)
```

You can do:

```
for i in range(4):
    g(a, b)
    a = h(a)
g(a, b)
```

a bit more compact

Comment: range isn't a statement, should have parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

First off you should use arguments and return values, and not side effects (i.e. returning or modifying global variables). I find that the use of `global result` makes your code unreadable, but I think you are asking about dynamic function composition, which can be expressed like this:

```
def compose(*fv):
    return reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), fv)
```

And then used like this (note that the evaluation order is right-to-left, which is common):

```
def add1(x): return x + 1
def mul2(x): return x * 2

>>> compose(add1, add1, add1)(1)
4
>>> compose(mul2, add1, add1, add1)(1)
8
```

This is common in functional languages, but I find that when you want this pattern in python, you're not making things simple enough.